# How to programmatically create check-in place on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, checkin

How do you programmatically create a check-in place on Facebook? The graph API allows you to check-in on existing place (which is represented by a page. You pass coordinates and server returns an array with places with given accuracy and then you can select where to check-in). What I need is to be able to pass coordinates (long and lat) and either check-in if the page of place is exists or create new (I have all the information, ie. address, phone, id etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do it with current FB public API.
There is a bug report: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13388

See also discussion on: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=82074

You may also try as workaround use webview showing touch.facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create new places via the API, only check into existing places.